# How can I bind the result from methode in a static class with parameters (only XAML)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have a methode in a static class and this expected two parameters and return a string.

Now should I like from my View (without ViewModel) bind this result. Is this possible?

Pseudocode:

```
xmlns:lang="clr-namespace:LanguageModule;assembly=LanguageModule"

<TextBlock Text="{x:Static lang:Translate[firstParameter, secondParameter]}"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check out the [ObjectDataProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.objectdataprovider.aspx)

> Use the  MethodName property to call a
>   method and use the  MethodParameters
>   property to pass parameters to the
>   method. You can then bind to the
>   results of the method.

Here is an example article how to bind to a static method:

http://www.thomasclaudiushuber.com/blog/2008/01/10/bind-to-methods-with-objectdataprovider/

HTH